# Does Spring MVC URI Template processing implement RFC 6570?

Tags: spring, rfc, spring-el, uritemplate

I am trying to find a definitive answer as to how URI Templates in Spring MVC are parsed. 
The [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) links to the Draft RFC, but Spring is not listed in the [RFC's implementations page](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/wiki/Implementations)
On the other hand, [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) seems to suggest that they use SpEL.
Anyone has a  link that could clear this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classes involved on parsing URI Templates.

- `AntPathMatcher.extractUriTemplateVariables()`:  Used in `@RequestMapping` MVC annotation
- `UriTemplate` : Used in RestTemplate client.

You can use these classes to test how the URI Templates are parsed.

For example for MVC RequestMapping:

```
@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UriTemplateTest {

    private AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UriTemplateTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testUriTemplate() {
        Map<String, String> variables = matcher.extractUriTemplateVariables("/booking/hotel/{id}", "/booking/hotel/43");
        log.info(variables);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not support RFC6570,

For instance the first passes and the second fails.

```
@Test
public void thatUriPathVariablesWithSlashGetEncoded() {
    String uri = com.damnhandy.uri.template.UriTemplate.fromTemplate("http://localhost:80/context/entity/{var1}/{var2}").set("var1", "my/Id").set("var2", "blah").expand();

    Assert.assertThat(uri, Matchers.is("http://localhost:80/context/entity/my%2FId/blah"));
}

@Test
public void thatUriPathVariablesWithSlashGetEncodedWithSpring() {
    String uri = new org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate("http://localhost:80/context/entity/{var1}/{var2}").expand("my/Id", "blah")
            .toASCIIString();

    Assert.assertThat(uri, Matchers.is("http://localhost:80/context/entity/my%2FId/blah"));
}
```

There is a ticket open to add support one day. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10505